# Get Color Palettes from ColorHunt.co in Python

Tags: python

I am creating a Color Addon for Blender And I am trying to retrieve color Palettes From Famous sites. I would like to start with [ColorHunt](https://colorhunt.co). Basically as you can see on the site there are a lot of color palettes. I would like to get all the avaiable palettes in an array containing the HEX Values of the color in that palette, for example: ("FF0000", "ab1234", "cd337H", "ff0066") and so on. 
Is that possible?

Comment: You can use `http://www.colourlovers.com` because they provide rest api, Using python `requests` module you can make http request to get palette in `xml` format. For example the url `http://www.colourlovers.com/api/palettes/random` will return random color palette in `xml` format

Comment: Thanks for the sudgestion, but I'd prefer colorhunt as I am more familiar with it and it has all uniform color palettes

Comment: If `colorhunt` provides api then it's easy, But without api also it's possible but you need to extract `palette` information by extracting it from html

Comment: I think it doesn't provide an api because I found nothing by looking for it. How could I extract informtion from html so?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, at least as of today. However, don't use this method if you're building an app that you'd like to release on stores because the endpoint we'll fetch the palettes from may change without notice.

### Long story short: you can create a POST request to get palettes.

The params of the request are the following:

- the header Content-Type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`
- the endpoint is `https://colorhunt.co/php/feed.php`
- the request body is `{'step': 0, 'sort': 'random', 'tags': ''}`

You can choose the `sort` element among `random`, `new`, `trendy`, and `popular`.
The response you'll get is of the following type, and it's up to you to parse it:

```json
[
  {
    "code": "febfb3e1396c96d38cd0f9b1",
    "likes": "1682",
    "date": "4 years"
  },
  ...
]
```

Then you'll need to parse the `code` value `febfb3e1396c96d38cd0f9b1`:
you'll notice a pattern, the series of 4 hex color codes of the given palette: `febfb3 | e1396c | 96d38c | d0f9b1`.

### Warning!

I recommend you to only use this method for 'recreational' purposes because it's not the official API, and I don't know if Gal Shir will build one (he said so, once) or if he won't. So, the endpoint could change again. Just FYI, last month I could get the palettes from `https://colorhunt.co/hunt.php` and the response was quite different.

Cheers and happy coding everyone!

Answer (score -1):

Or, you could use web scraping.
Here's a quick overview of web scraping vs. a POST/GET request:

- Web Scraping:

  - Gets the HTML that's sent to the client from the page
- POST/GET:

  - Asks the page for some content following a protocol and with headers/parameters: this is what's used with APIs, but we don't know if ColorHunt provides them

Here's a good introduction to Python web scraping:
https://realpython.com/python-web-scraping-practical-introduction/